# How to find the build / UBR / kernel version of Windows 10 using command-line (cmd)

Tags: windows, command-line, prompt

I would like to know the basic commands in prompt windows. Therefore, I want to begin by knowing the command that return details of my operating system like kernel version / build and UBR (Update Build Revision).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I want to know my OS kernel version / build and UBR (Update Build Revision).

Use the following command in a `cmd` shell:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
```

Example output:

```
> systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.14393 N/A Build 14393
```

And in PowerShell:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object  Caption, CSDVersion, ServicePackMajorVersion, BuildNumber | FL
```

Example output:

```
Caption                 : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
CSDVersion              : 
ServicePackMajorVersion : 0
BuildNumber             : 14393
```

Or:

```
[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version
```

Example output:

```
> [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      14393  0
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [systeminfo](https://ss64.com/nt/systeminfo.html) - List system configuration

Comment: This does not return the update build revision (UBR). Specifically, some of the commands above report that it is 0, but it is likely not zero on your system if you run a "ver" command or equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Run this from the cmd prompt:

```
c:\> ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1158]
```